# c++ Handling queue overflow

Tags: c++, overflow, deque

I am creating a thread which puts data into the message queue which is defined as follows:

```
std::deque<struct MessageDetails> MsgQueue;

struct MessageDetails{
    char msg[256];
    uint64_t Signature;
    int32_t Id;
    int32_t Mask;
    bool Valid;
};
```

Ideally the other module should `pop` the data from this queue and process it.
But for error handling in my code , In case the other module is not processing any data (or not processing too quickly) then the message queue size keeps on increasing and may be at some point of time lead to overflow.

I wanted know when will it overflow(what is the allocated size?) and how can I handle that? Is there any error that I can capture?

Comment: if the answer solves your problem, you have to mark it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a try catch block while inserting into dequeu:

```
try {
    MsgQueue.insert(xxx)
} catch (std::bad_alloc & e) {
    //Add logic to handle queue overflow
}
```

also you can do compare

```
MsQueue.max_size() and MsQueue.size()
```

and if there is no enough capacity try

```
MsQueue.resize
```

Comment: I am not sure if comparison between MsQueue.max_size() and MsQueue.size()  would work. As described in the documentation for max_size() it says that :

 This is the maximum potential size the container can reach due to known system or library implementation limitations, but the container is by no means guaranteed to be able to reach that size: it can still fail to allocate storage at any point before that size is reached.

If it fails to allocate before it reaches max_size what can be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a count of the items you have added to the queue, you can see the code from the following link.

[queue::max_size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/max_size/)

Comment: It is not guaranteed always that the container is able to reach that size: it can still fail to allocate storage at any point before that size is reached.

Comment: you can always use a try catch block as mentioned in Akhil's(@Akhil Thayyil) answer to catch such exceptions.